# Loading data into a uitableview in a uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am trying to load data from an array which was made by parsing json... I have the json data in the arrays for sure, but the table view methods are not even being called... I have the table view embedded in a regular uiviewcontroller, it compiles and everything the table just loads no data.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [transactions count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"any cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"any cell"] autorelease];
    }

    NSLog(@"got here");
    cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [prices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    prices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self requestTransactionData];
}
```

And here's my .h file...

```
@interface Controller1 : UIViewController
    <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;

    IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *totalLabel;

    NSMutableArray *names;
    NSArray *transactions;
    NSMutableArray *prices;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *totalLabel;

@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTableView;
```

I can't use ARC for this project. I also have it hooked up properly in the interface builder... These seems rather easy but for some reason I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set the delegate and the data source of the table view? Why aren't you using a table view controller?

Comment: I have to have a label under the table with the totals... I did this:  <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> in the view controller .h file

Comment: You still need to set it as the delegate and the data source. Something like `[myTabelView setDelegate: self];` and `[myTableView setDataSource: self];`. With `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` you have only told the compiler that your class conforms to these protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't see how you know the data source methods are not being called. You are not logging all of them. If`numberOfRowsInSection` is called before `transactions` is populated or is nil, it returns zero and that's the end of that.
2. Try calling `reloadData` using delayed performance so that it happens *after* `transactions` is populated. The table view doesn't magically know when your data is ready; you have to tell it.

Comment: I have a log statement in the cellForRowAtIndexPath that never shows up

Comment: wait a second, i just used a log in numberOfRowsInSection and they are getting called its just that its returning 0. you're right. How Can I delay the call?

Comment: So I was able to do the delayed call... but I get an EXC_Bad_Access error, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

call `sef.tableView reloadData` after names the prices were filled in `requestTransactionData`